# Matrix $A^tA$ properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Given A any matrix, prove that $A^tA$ 
is positive definite if $\ker(A)=0$,
and always positive semi-definite.

Comment: Look for "Gram-matrix".

Answer (score 2):

$ \langle A^{t}Ax, x \rangle =\|Ax\|^{2} \geq 0$ so $A^{t}A$ is always positive semidefinite. It is positive definite iff $\|Ax\|=0$ only for $x=0$ which means $ker (A)=\{0\}$.